# Why can a strongly-typed enum be initialized with an integer without static_cast?

Tags: c++, enums, standards, c++17, type-safety

```
enum class E
{};

int main()
{
    E e1{ 0 }; // ok

    E e2 = 0; // not ok
    // error : cannot initialize a variable of
    // type 'E' with an rvalue of type 'int'
}
```

My compiler is `clang 4.0` with option `-std=c++1z`.

It is expected that `E e2 = 0;` is not ok, because `E` is strongly-typed. However, what surprised me is that `E e1{ 0 };` should be ok.

Why can a strongly-typed enum be initialized with an integer without `static_cast`?

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) that is allowed since C++17

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looking at the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) using list intializers is allowed since C++17:

> Both scoped enumeration types and unscoped enumeration types whose
>   underlying type is fixed can be initialized from an integer without a
>   cast, using list initialization, if all of the following is true:
>
> - the initialization is direct-list-initialization
> - the initializer list has only a single element
> - the enumeration is either scoped or unscoped with underlying type fixed
> - the conversion is non-narrowing

Clang supports this since version 3.9 (according to the [implementation status page](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#cxx17))

GCC supports this since version 7 (according to the [standards support page](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx1z))

See this C++ proposal for additional context and motivation: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0138r2.pdf